# Form submission from link vs Form submission from button (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a form which contains a link. If the user clicks on the `<a>` tag, it is supposed to submit the `<form>` using jQuery. However, in Chrome it fails silently. It works fine in Firefox.

I have found that if I change the `a` to a `button` element it works fine, even in Chrome. Can anyone explain this?

```js
function javaScriptSubmit() {
  alert('Simulate submit!');
  $('#RetrieveQuote').submit();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="RetrieveQuote" method="post" action="javascript:alert('action!')">
  <input id="myName" value="David"> <br/>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javaScriptSubmit()">Submit from link</a>
  <button onclick="javaScriptSubmit()">Submit from button</button>
</form>
```

If you're in Chrome and click on the link, the action alert is never called. However, if you click on the button, you see both alert messages. Clicking on either works in FireFox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="RetrieveQuote" method="post" action="javascript:alert('action!')">
      <input id="myName" value="David" /> <br />
      <a href="#" id="submit-link">Submit from link</a>
      <button>Submit from button</button>
    </form>
    <script>
      $("#submit-link").click(function() {
        $("#RetrieveQuote").submit();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've done a bit more testing and it's not the setup of the event handler which solves it, it's getting rid of the href="javascript:void(0)" which fixes it.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is happening here?